# How can I intercept reading the value of a text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm working on some Greasemonkey / Tampermonkey scripts for various third party websites. (Adding Unicode normalization of Vietnamese text input with combining characters to precomposed characters as the websites expect.)

On simple sites I've been able to find which events they trap, usually submit, and process the content of the text input before the site script deals with it.

But on AJAXy sites they might do things like testing the input on each keypress or on a timer. (I don't want to change the text normalization while typing because it messes up the semantics of backspacing to change tone marks).

Is there a way I can trap each time the site's script tries to get the text in the input element from the DOM? Maybe something with `prototype`, which I've never used before, or will that not since it's dealing with DOM / host objects, etc?

The site I'm currently working on seems to always use jQuery `.val()` to get the text value of the text input though. I'm guessing there must at least be some esoteric way to intercept jQuery, but I would really like to know my options for intercepting this at the lowest level too, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can change what page ***javascript*** sees<sup>2</sup> by overriding an `<input>`'s `value`-property's getter.  Note that **this one override also changes what jQuery and other libraries see**:

```
Object.defineProperty (HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value", {
    get: function () {
        return "xxx";
        //return this.value;  //-- Warning! This causes infinite recursion.
    }
} );
```

The *snippet*, below, shows a more practical example (Firefox only. I don't think there's a workable way to do this in Chrome without serious complications -- see referenced bug(s), below.)

This example reports an input's value normally until you press the "spoof" button. Press the "List" button to see what javascript thinks the input's value is.:

```js
window.fakeInput = false;

$(document).ready (jQueryMain);

function ListValue (preamble) {
    $("#Output").append ('<li>' + preamble + $("#inpTarg").val() + '</li>');
}

function jQueryMain () {
    //-- This works on Firefox but not Chrome!
    var oldInpValDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor (HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value");
    if (oldInpValDescriptor == null) {
        // See Chrome issue 43394 and many related.
        alert ('This browser does not support overriding the value property');
        return;
    }
    Object.defineProperty (HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value", {
        get: function () {
            if (window.fakeInput && this.id == "inpTarg") {
                console.log ("Spoofing...");
                return document.getElementById ("inpSpoof").value;
            }

            return oldInpValDescriptor.get.call (this);
        }
    } );

    $("#btnPrint").click ( function () {
        ListValue ('');
    } );

    $("#btnHijack").click ( function () {
        window.fakeInput    = ! window.fakeInput;
        var onOffStr        = window.fakeInput ? "on" : "off";

        if (window.fakeInput)
            $("#btnHijack").text ('Restore Input');
        else
            $("#btnHijack").text ('Hijack Input');

        ListValue ('Hijack ' + onOffStr + '. Value = ');
    } );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <label>Target value:<input type="text" value="I'm not safe!" id="inpTarg"></label> <br>
    <label>Spoof value:<input type="text" value="I'm perfectly fine. ;)" id="inpSpoof"></label>
</p>
<p>
    <button id="btnHijack">Hijack Input</button> <br>
    <button id="btnPrint">List value</button> <br>
</p>
<ol id="Output"></ol>
```

### Warnings:

1. This smells like an "x Y" problem. Answering the question asked, but this kind of approach is probably not the best way to solve any real-life problem.
2. This does not override what is sent to a server on an HTML form submit. The targeted server will see the unspoofed value.
3. In a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script, **the override code must operate in the page's scope.**  That is, use `@grant none` or inject the code.
4. This **currently does not work in Chrome!**  See [Issue 43394](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43394) and the many related bugs.

Comment: Feel free to include a bit of answer, or a comment about answering in a non 'x Y' fashion if you like.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but there is not enough info to answer any more relevantly.  The question needs an MCVE for that.  As for answering in a non 'x y' fashion, that is covered [here on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/148310).  I answered this Q anyway: (1) because it's an interesting problem and maybe a security issue, (2) just in case. ;)

Comment: I don't think I could come up with an MCVE without knowing the inner workings of the 3rd party website I'm patching with a userscript \-:

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for the jQuery case, but not yet for the low-level / non-jQuery case.

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery.valHooks.text = {
  get: function (elem) {
    // check fields of elem if only intercepting specific text elements
    return doSomeTransformation(elem.value);
  }
};
```

I found the solution in [a three-year old post on the blog of Rodney Rehm](http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/11-jQuery-Hooks.html#val) using the, apparently undocumented, jQuery feature known as `valHooks`.